# pyglet WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media

Tags: media-player, pyglet

I don't understand what is going wrong here. Everytime I attempt to play a sound in pyglet, I get the following error:
`WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media`.

These are the things I have attempted:

- Installing versions 5-10 of AVbin manually and resetting my computer after each install, just to be sure that this wasn't the problem. I have attempted both x64 and x86 versions.
- Installing it via the AVbin installer.

I tried AVbin 5 as this was the one that is pre packaged with the pyglet installer, which I can't use due to an error with python 2.7.5. I would like to keep using python 2.7 as allot of modules that I often use are installed for 2.7. Any help on this situation?

Also, this is on windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**From the pyglet.org Programming Guide:**

*"Decoding of compressed audio and video is provided by AVbin. If AVbin is not present, pyglet will fall back to reading uncompressed WAV files only."*

So this means AVbin is needed to decode and play different audio formats, other than .WAV.

I had this same problem, using Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7.6 with pyglet.

I tried installing version 5 and version 10 of AVbin, I tried to copy the .dll file to windows/system32 folder etc., but none of these worked.

**This way I got the sounds working:**

1. Download the windows version of AVbin 5 from here: 
   http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Home/Home.html
2. Copy the avbin.dll to your project folder. (The folder where your .py file resides.)

This works for me. Hope it works for you aswell.

Answer (score 0):

WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media

1:- Download the windows version of AVbin from here: 
    http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Home/Home.html

2:- Copy the avbin.dll to your C:\Windows\System or C:\Windows\System32